# How to retrieve a file without knowing doctype

Tags: c#, file-io

I query a main folder from a list of doc names.
The doctype is arbitrary.
Each file is stored in a folder with the same name.

Sample structure:

Main folder

-> bacon --> bacon.doc

-> cherry --> cherry.pdf

Right now I have code:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"\\Main folder\\ + string[i] + "\\" + string[i]);
```

but I don't know what to append to it so that it searches for any file of the same string[i].

Comment: What if there are more files in a folder? (e.g. `cherry.doc` and `cherry.pdf`)

Comment: @walkhard that issue does not apply to my context

Comment: It may have influence on solution (e.g. you can take first file which name starts with `cheery` etc)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at something like this...

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
// returns:
// "c:\MyDir\my-car.BMP"
// "c:\MyDir\my-house.jpg"
```

Grab the filepaths first. Then use that for the FileInfo constructor.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/